# How to understand print result of byte data read from a pickle file?

Tags: python, hex, pickle

I am trying to get data from pickle file. As I know, when we do serialization, the data is converted into byte stream. When I read the data as binary using this code:

```
f = open("alexnet.pth", "rb")
data = f.read()
```

I got this result

> b'PK\x03\x04\x00\x00\x08\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x12\x00archive/data.pklFB\x0e\x00ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ\x80\x02ccollections\nOrderedDict\nq\x00)Rq\x01(X\x11\x00\x00\x00features.0.weightq\x02ctorch._utils\n_rebuild_tensor_v2\nq\x03((X\x07\x00\x00\x00storageq\x04ctorch\nFloatStorage\nq\x05X\r\x00\x00\x002472041505024q\x06X\x03\x00\x00\x00cpuq\x07M\xc0Ztq\x08QK\x00(K@K\x03K\x0bK\x0btq\t(Mk\x01KyK\x0bK\x01tq\n\x89h\x00)Rq\x0btq\x0cRq\rX\x0f\x00\x00\x00features.0.biasq\x0eh\x03((h\x04h\x05X\r\x00\x00\x002472041504928q\x0fh\x07K@tq\x10QK\x00K@\x85q\x11K\x01\x85q\x12\x89h\x00)Rq\x13tq\x14Rq\x15X\x11\x00\x00\x00features.3.weightq\x16h\x03((h\x04h\x05X\r\x00\x00\x002472041505120q\x17h\x07J\x00\xb0\x04\x00tq\x18QK\x00(K\xc0K@K\x05K\x05tq\x19(M@\x06K\x19K\x05K\x01tq\x1a\x89h\x00)Rq\x1btq\x1cRq\x1dX\x0f\x00\x00\x00features.3.biasq\x1eh\x03((h\x04h\x05X\r\x00\x00\x002472041507136q\x1fh\x07K\xc0tqQK\x00K\xc0\x85q!K\x01\x85q"\x89h\x00)Rq#tq$Rq%X\x11\x00\x00\x00features.6.weightq&h\x03((h\x04h\x05X\r\x00\x00\x002472041509056q'h\x07J\x00 \n\x00tq(QK\x00(M\x80\x01K\xc0K\x03K\x03tq)(M\xc0\x06K\tK\x03K\x01tq*\x89h\x00)Rq+tq,Rq-X\x0f\x00\x00\x00features.6.biasq.h\x03((h\x04h\x05X\r\x00\x00\x002472041505312q/h\x07M\x80\x01tq0QK\x00M\x80\x01\x85q1K\x01\x85q2\x89h\x00)Rq3tq4Rq5X\x11\x00\x00\x00features.8.weightq6h\x03((h\x04h\x05X\r\x00\x00\x002472041508192q7h\x07J\x00\x80\r\x00tq8QK\x00(M\x00\x01M\x80\x01K\x03K\x03tq9(M\x80\rK\tK\x03K\x01tq:\x89h\x00)Rq;tq<Rq=X\x0f\x00\x00\x00features.8.biasq>h\x03((h\x04h\x05X\r\

I know those are hexadecimal characters. My question is does 1 byte contain 1 hexadecimal character (every "\" means 1 byte)? Or how to read this in terms of byte? Also I notice there are some English words such as "\x02ctorch._utils" and "n_rebuild_tensor_v2". What do they mean (hexadecimal + string)?

Comment: Why not read it with an actual function designed for unpickling, i.e `pickle.load`?

Comment: Because I am trying to learn hufmann coding using this data

Comment: If I'm not mistaking a ```.pth``` file is a PyTorch file.  You could use PyTorch's ```load()``` function to read these files.

Comment: @ryanchandra But the unpickling (or whatever that is, as the `.pth` extension doesn't suggest it being an actual pickle) process itself has nothing to do with Huffman coding and trying to extract this manually will make things way harder than they are supposed to be.

Comment: When you print a bytes object in Python, by default ASCII printable characters are shown in their printable form, and non-printable characters are shown in hex notation. So a byte with hex value 4E is shown as `N` but a byte with hex value 04 is shown as `\x04`. If you want to see the whole thing in hex notation then `print(data.hex())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does 1 byte contain 1 hexadecimal character (every "" means 1 byte)?

Technically, 1 byte can be represented by a number between 0 and 255, which is often represented by two hexadecimal character from 00 to FF, expressed in python as \x00 to \xFF. So yes, in a sense every "\" means one byte, but every 'normal' letter is a byte too. Python just chooses to print the ASCII character if the byte corresponds to a printable character in ASCII (numbers 32-126), and the '\x__'-representation if it doesn't ('ASCII control character' or >=128). But if a byte is printed as a character, that doesn't mean it was meant to be a character in the original data! (Although the readable function names surely are).

> How to read this in terms of byte?

If you know what the byte is supposed to represent (int16, int32, float, char, ascii, utf-8, ...), you can convert them with Pythons [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module. Otherwise this representation is a good as any other.

> Also I notice there are some English words such as "\x02ctorch._utils" and "n_rebuild_tensor_v2". What do they mean (hexadecimal + string)?

As mentioned, these are just these strings encoded in the data as ASCII (or UTF-8, no difference in this case). The non-printable byte in front is probably part of the data that comes before, there is no way to know for sure without knowing this particular format.

As others have mentioned, there is not much to gain here by poking around this data. The code that writes these files is [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/serialization.html#save). There is a lot of pickling and zipping going on, which mangles the original data even further.

But its always good to poke around!

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help. Actually I just want to try Huffman algorithm to assign codeword for each character and dont really care about the original data. Once again, I really appreciate your help

Comment: In that case, its probably best to start with a large body of text, this is where Huffman coding really shines. Just use `.encode()` to convert to bytes